# The value of my score calculating variable increases abnormally

Tags: c, debugging, cmd

Programmed a space invader-ish type game in C. Everything runs smoothly except sometimes the value of 'score'(to keep tabs on score which increase every time an invader dies) increments hundreds of thousand times randomly. Can't figure out why. Full code in case someone needs it [Cmd space invaders](https://gist.github.com/Redcoat314/98a75a36e8869badb833607c684c8931)

```
void laserUpdate(){
char explosion = 'X';
//laser control
for(i = 0; i < xAxis; i++){     
    for(j = yAxis - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        if(world[j][i] == invaderLaser){                        
            if(world[j + 1][i] == shield){                          
                world[j + 1][i] = ' ';                      
                world[j][i] = ' ';                      
            }                   
            else if(world[j + 1][i] == player){                     
                world[j + 1][i] = explosion;                                            
                victory = 0;                        
                break;                          
            }                   
            else if(world[j + 1][i] == playerLaser){                    
                world[j][i] = explosion;                        
                world[j + 1][i] = ' ';                  
            }                   
            else{
                world[j + 1][i] = invaderLaser;                     
                world[j][i] = ' ';                  
            }                   
        }                   
        else if(world[j][i] == playerLaser){                        
            if(world[j - 1][i] == invaderLaser){                            
                world[j - 1][i] = explosion;                            
                world[j][i] = ' ';                                              
            }                                   
            else if(world[j - 1][i] == invader){                    
                world[j - 1][i] = explosion;                        
                world[j][i] = ' ';                      
                score += 50;                        
                totalInvaders--;                                                
                if(totalInvaders == 0){                         
                    victory = 0;                            
                    break;          
                }                                           
            }                   
            else if(world[j - 1][i] == shield){                     
                world[j][i] = ' ';                      
            }                   
            else{                       
                world[j][i] = ' ';
                world[j - 1][i] = playerLaser;
                j--;
            }
        }
        else if(world[j][i] == explosion){
            print();
            Sleep(50);
            world[j][i] = ' ';
        }   
        invaderLaserProduction();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's identical to space invader if you are familiar with it. Also, which debugger do you use?

Comment: I can see some potential buffer overflow in your code. Eg, when j = yAxis - 1, if the first condition "world[j][i] == invaderLaser" is true, you are reading out of your buffer "world[j + 1][i] == shield", and maybe writing too "world[j + 1][i] = ' ';"

It is a risk and it could evoke the random behaviour!!

I don't say it is the root cause, but it could be!

Comment: @coderredoc Dev c++

Comment: @Redcoat.: So you sayinng that at times score increases many times for single hit? I am notifcing a strange thing....sometimes even if i hit the score is not increased

Comment: @Alejandro but the condition won't be true so it won't affect the flow

Comment: @coderredoc the plot thickens

Comment: @Alejandro agreed, poor bounds checking.

Comment: @Redcoat it is irrelavent whether the condition is true or false, when you are indexing outside the array bounds.

Comment: Just like UB is....

Comment: This urgently needs smoe kind of lookup table instead of this byzantine mess of `if` statements.

Comment: @Weather Vane if i add a check in the first condition if the element is near the boundary and purge it there, will it be fine then?

Comment: @tadman teach me master

Comment: I've given you the key term to look for, the technique which can save you a lot of time, so [resources like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) can explain further.

Comment: @tadman appreciate it man. I'm a bit slow, apologies.

Comment: Recommendation! Split into inline functions to make it easier to follow and check, and make easier reuse code blocks! Looks like the blocks inside the if's are very similar ;) !
inline void handleInvaderLaser(world, int posx, int posy)
inline void handlePlayerLaser(world, int posx, int posy)
inline void handleExplosion(world, int posx, int posy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on whether the game field wraps on both edges, or is off-limits. Either way, you have to deal with

```
world[j + 1][i]
```

which indexes out of bounds when `j == yAxis - 1`, and

```
world[j - 1][i]
```

which indexes out of bounds when `j == 0`.

These conditions are at the start and finish of the  `j` loop.